# React Native: Use component state for a fetch request

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently using `fetch()` to post an HTTP request with the following code:

```
  getAuthToken = () => {
    fetch('https://example.com/api/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: 'userstring',
        password: 'passstring',
      }),
    }
  )
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    return responseJson.token;
  });
  }
```

I would like to pass state from the component as the `body` data for the request. I am using `JSON.stringify()` to format a JSON string for the request `body`, but I don't know how to access the component `state` at this point:

```
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: 'userstring',
    password: 'passstring',
  }),
```

One attempted I made was to do this:

```
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: {this.state.username},
    password: {this.state.password},
  }),
```

The code above produced an error. I also attempted to use `{{this.state.username}}` but that also gave the same syntax error.

Is there away I can achieve what I want? I'm passing dynamic input fields and I would like to just have that field be the value of state. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getAuthToken()` is defined in your component class, then you should be able to access the state object directly, without the `{ .. }` syntax. One approach might be as follows:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

    // If getAuthToken defined as class field then it can access this.state
    getAuthToken = () => {

        // If state not initialized, early exit
        if(!this.state) {
            return
        }

        // Extract username and password from state
        const { username, password } = this.state

        fetch('https://example.com/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                // Use authentication data from form in request
                username,
                password,
            })
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((responseJson) => responseJson.token)
        .then((token) => {
            console.log(`token:${token}`)
        });
    }
}
```

Depending on the implementation of your component, it may be worth validating the `state` of your component before attempting to extract and post authentication data from it, as shown above with:

```
if(!this.state) {
    return
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It helps a lot.  I get token undefined thou.  I've tried this: username, password and         username: username,
        password: password . @Dacre Denny

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps your server's response is different to what you expect. What happens if you remove the last `.then()` (with console.log), and update the `.then()` (with `responseJson`) to this? `.then((responseJson) => alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson)))` . What does the alert() dialog print?

Comment: When I manually input username and password like so: username: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        password: 'mypasword',  @Dacre Denny it works.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you add `alert(username + ',' + password)` just before the `fetch()`? Does the prompt show expected data from your form?

Comment: This is going to be the problem I console logged and I'm not updating state.  I'll fix that but as for this it works as you suggested re this question.  THANK YOU!  @Dacre Denny